# dynamic directive: templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive

I really need help by solving the following problem:

I try to realize some settings for an application, therefore I want to use the **UI-Bootstrap accordion**.

---

I have the following **HTML-Code**:

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.groupTitle}}">
        <accordion-content></accordion-content>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

The DOM of the "accordion" is a `div` where `ng-controller="AccordionController"`. In this Controller I have a variable `groups` which looks like this:

```
$scope.groups = [{
        groupTitle: "title1",
        templateUrl: "file1.html"
    }, {
        groupTitle: "title2",
        templateUrl: "file2.html"
    }]; // ... and so on
```

---

`accordionContent` is my directive which should give different templateURLs depending on the `$index` or `groupTitle` (doesn't matter).

The `accordionContent`-directive looks like this:

```
settings.directive("accordionContent", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: //**here is my problem**
    };
});
```

The content also has some angular-stuff implemented, I read that this need to get considered. (or not ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that like that. I tried myself once, didn't work if I remember correctly.

What you can do is have a static HTML page in the directive, and in that HTML page you'll have:

```
<div>
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
</div>
```

Where `templateUrl` is the variable on your isolated scope (or not isolated..) in the `accordion-content` directive.

Comment: I made it with that `div` and `ng-include="group.templateUrl"` in the `ng-repeat` - Thank you very very much!